# How does the following C function work?

Tags: c

I am checking for string anagram. But I am not able to understand the logic behind
the `int check_anagram(char a[], char b[])` function.

This code only gives either lower case or upper case string anagram.
I want to make it case insensitive. Kindly provide necessary changes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int check_anagram(char [], char []);

int main()
{
   char a[100], b[100];
   int flag;

   printf("Enter first string\n");
   gets(a);

   printf("Enter second string\n");
   gets(b);

   flag = check_anagram(a, b);

   if (flag == 1)
      printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are anagrams.\n", a, b);
   else
      printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are not anagrams.\n", a, b);
   system("pause");
   return 0;

}




    int check_anagram(char a[], char b[])
    {
       int first[26] = {0}, second[26] = {0}, c = 0;

       while (a[c] != '\0')
       {
          first[a[c]-'a']++;
          c++;
       }

       c = 0;

       while (b[c] != '\0')
       {
          second[b[c]-'a']++;
          c++;
       }

       for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
       {
          if (first[c] != second[c])
             return 0;
       }

       return 1;
    }
```

Please kindly explain:

1. `first[a[c]-'a']++;`
2. `second[b[c]-'a']++;`

Comment: You've given no indication of what you've tried or what difficulty you're having understanding the code presented. In short, it *sounds* like you were given a homework assignment but weren't paying attention in class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first[a[c]-'a']++;
```

Is taking alphabet index (0-26) of the c-th letter of string 'a'. For example if we have input "test" then for each letter this a[c] equates to:

't', 'e', 's', 't'

Then a[c] - 'a' equates to (where 'a' == 97 and 't' == 116):

19, 4, 18, 19

Then first[a[c] - 'a']++ increments the a the alphabetic index of each character so first would end up like:

```
 a       e                           s t
{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

To make your code work, you simply can pre-format each string so that they are both lower case, or do a check for upper case chars and add 32 (the ascii difference). Look at an ascii table to help you, there is one here: [ASCII TABLE - IMAGE](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/images/ASCII1.GIF)

Answer (score 1):

`a[c]` is a `char`. Characters are represented in C via ASCII, a code that uses a different integera in the range 0-255 for characters. Arithmetic with `char`s is done via these codes.

The letters a-z are ASCII encoded by a continuous set of integers, so you can use an expression like `letter - 'a'`, when `letter` is a lowercase letter, to get an index for that letter. (ie, `'a' - 'a'` is 0, `'b' - 'a'` is 1, `'c' - 'a'` is 2, etc.) This lets you easily convert letters into indexes for use in an array.